# How to Reset IOS folder in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, npm

I'm working on a react-native application, I made some mistakes on the iOS project side. Android goes well and no problems. I would like to know if there is any solution to completely reset the iOS project without losing the Android project.

When running the `react-native run-ios` command, the iOS simulator starts and remains locked in `info IDEDerivedDataPathOverride`

What I tried to do:

```
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

-------- the same problem, did not work

I check on npm and I found a package `react-native-clean-project`
and i ran: `./node_modules/.bin/react-native-clean-project --remove-iOS-build`

-------- the same problem

```
rm -rf ios/build
```

-------- the same problem

and in last thing i remove the node_modules folder, install it again, clean the cache, but is the same problem...

I want to make a fresh ios folder, like when create a fresh project, 
but just for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Delete /ios folders

Run `$react-native upgrade` to generate /ios folder again.

Run `$react-native link`

Run `$react-native run-ios` .

Comment: After $react-native upgrade , in my project was reset both android and ios, and after this when i run $react-native link a got this err: ERR! ERRPACKAGEJSON No package found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? , but i'm in project, i tried $npm install --save but same error :(

Answer (score 0):

This is my solutuion... (partially)

Downgrade the version of my repo, i pulled 2 commits behind

The after i tried to do:

```
watchman watch-del-all && 
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-native-packager-cache-* &&
rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && 
rm -rf node_modules/ 
&& npm cache clean --force &&
npm install
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

(but i have some errs on watchman, is something like “watch-dell-all” si not a common command)

Then after a tried this:

```
sudo npm cache clean —force

npm install —save

react-native run-ios
```

No result here, so i decided to remove node_modules and after that to install via yarn (i don't know why) but after this i finally open my project in Xcode when i'we made a build from Xcode.. I've linked again with react-native link after that now, i can run react-native run-ios but i have some errors on FBSDKShareKit, i'm working now to solve that.

Comment: any solution you found?